# I am having issues with tcpdump in terminal

Tags: terminal, compiler-errors, tcpdump, osx-yosemite

I always end up with this error message, "tcpdump: ioctl(SIOCIFCREATE): Operation not permitted" 
Any ideas to what I am doing wrong. I am running this on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: You need to include code so we know what is causing the error, check here for some advice: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Any ideas to what I am doing wrong

Not running tcpdump as root.  On Yosemite and later, tcpdump captures on the "any" device by default, and setting up an "any" device requires root privileges - not just the ability to open the BPF devices.

Comment: this is the answer, i.e. `sudo tcpdump`

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo tcpdump`.

*You have to run it as a root because of macos security.*